# Why does winegdb does not dissasmbly correctly when using x/i $pc

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, gdb

I am trying to debug a program in wine with winegdb but dissassembling instructions at a specific point in the code results different when compared to Wdasm dissassembled binary, though `x/10x $pc` shows the byte code is the same as Wdasm disassembled byte code.

```
   Wine-gdb> x/10i $pc
=> 0x4029bb:    int3   
   0x4029bc:    test   %esi,%esp
   0x4029be:    (bad)  
   0x4029bf:    (bad)  
   0x4029c0:    incl   (%eax)
   0x4029c2:    add    %al,(%eax)
   0x4029c4:    add    %bl,%ch
   0x4029c6:    inc    %ebp
   0x4029c7:    aam    $0xdc
   0x4029c9:    popf   
Wine-gdb> x/10x $pc
0x4029bb:   0xfef485c7  0x0000ffff  0x45dd0000  0x389ddcd4
0x4029cb:   0xdfffffff  0x40c4f6e0  0x85c70c75  0xfffffef0
0x4029db:   0x00000001  0x85c70aeb
```

[Wdasm disassembled code at point 0x004029bb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tloam.png)

Comment: Looks like a bug. `wine-gdb` is disassembling its own software breakpoint. It should normally hide that from you just as it is hidden in the memory dump.

Comment: I am breaking into using $kill -SIGINT `pidof gdb`. Additionally correcting the first byte @0x04029bb which is 0xCC (int 3) (that is highly because of sent SIGINT) according to x/i $pc does not fix the rest of the disassembled code.

Comment: But you do have a breakpoint there, right? Otherwise I don't see any reason for the `int3` in there.

Comment: Yes i have a break point at that location

Comment: It's leaking out due to a bug. If `wine-gdb` supports hardware breakpoints, then use those. Alternatively, see if it goes away if you disable the breakpoint once stopped.

Comment: I realized that sending SIGINT is not related to that breakpoint @0x004029bb

Comment: Ok this is a software breakpoint right.

Comment: `Wine-gdb> set {char} 0x04029bb = 0xc7
Wine-gdb> x/10i $pc
=> 0x4029bb: movl   $0x0,-0x10c(%ebp)
    0x4029c5: fldl   -0x2c(%ebp)
    0x4029c8: fcompl -0xc8(%ebp)
   0x4029ce: fnstsw %ax
  0x4029d0: test   $0x40,%ah
   0x4029d3: jne    0x4029e1
   0x4029d5: movl   $0x1,-0x110(%ebp)
   0x4029df: jmp    0x4029eb
   0x4029e1: movl   $0x0,-0x110(%ebp)
   0x4029eb: mov    -0x110(%ebp),%edx`

Comment: Looks correct to me, which one in particular do you think is wrong?

Comment: Even I correct the first byte @0x004029bb which is INT 3 but below it is shown as 0xc7 does not fix the rest of the code.

Comment: Wdasm disassembled code starts with is mov dword ptr instruction at that location but above which is fixed with changing 0xcc to 0xc7 starts with movl $0x0...

Comment: No idea about `wine-gdb` but pure `gdb` can be switched to intel syntax by `set disassembly-flavor intel`.

Comment: Ok the resolving code is same as Wdasm resolves it thank you very much. I There is some syntax differences between them.